# Cannot get php session variable to set a var in javascript

Tags: php, javascript

I have a session variable called `$_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE']` in my php file which is set to a 2 character string. The php script redirects to an HTML file where I want to get the php session variable into a javascript variable.

I am using it in my javascript as follows, but I get nothing in the javascript variable.

```
var user_type = <?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE']; ?>;
```

This does not work.

Further to input received from other users, I tried the following :

```
var user_type = '<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE']) ?>';
```

Javascript returns a syntax error to the above.

I then tried

```
user_type = "<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE']) ?>";
```

This does not give an error in Javascript. However it returns the following value to user_type which is :

```
<?php echo json_encode($_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE']) ?>

$_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE'] is set to the string 'WO'.
```

Comment: var user_type = '<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE']; ?>';

Comment: 1) you did not enclose the value in quotes in JS; 2) you should call `addslashes($_SESSION['xxx'])`.

Answer (score 4):

Exactly what's the value in that session variable? If it's a string, you're generating invalid Javascript and causing a syntax error, e.g.:

```
<?php

$x = 'hello';

?>
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = <?php echo $x; ?>;
</script>
```

will give you

```
var x = hello;
```

and probably blow things up.

When dumping PHP data into a Javascript code block, especially when dynamically creating javascript values, **ALWAYS** use json_encode:

```
var x = <?php echo json_encode($x) ?>;
```

This will guarantee that you're producing syntactically valid JS.

Answer (score 0):

The file with that snippet of JavaScript will have to be parsed by PHP. The simplest way to do this is use the `.php` extension. PHP variables and statements will not work in non-PHP files (unless you configure your webserver to do so but that's probably way out of scope for this question). To use session vars, you also have to run `session_start()`.

For example

*some-file.php*

```
<?php session_start() ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<!-- snip -->

<script>
    var user_type = '<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE']; ?>';
</script>
```

As others have said, also include quotes around you JS strings.

Answer (score 0):

> The php script redirects to an HTML file where I want to get the php session variable into a javascript variable.

How can you get value of session variable in HTML Page?? You need PHP page for that. And in php page you can do like this

```
var user_type = "<?php echo $_SESSION['SESS_USER_TYPE']; ?>";
```